Calculating temporal metrics with a large dataset
I'm having an issue with a requirement to calculate different metrics for groups of users within a specific date range. We expect that by pressing a button, we can generate a PDF displaying these metrics, along with a .csv file attached to the main record (which contains the necessary parameters for the report). The issue lies in the amount of data I need to query from multiple records to process and obtain each metric.
I tried to handle this synchronously using a controller and a Visualforce page with readOnly = true, which allows me to increase the queried row limit from 50,000 to 1,000,000 records, which is great. However, no matter how much I've tried to optimize the processing logic, it always exceeds the 10,000ms CPU time limit. I then attempted to move the logic to asynchronous jobs using Queueable and a custom temporary metric object. In this case, the processing works perfectly in terms of CPU time, but the issue is that even if I split the work into smaller chunks, the limits are aggregated for the entire queue, so I easily exceed the 50,000 query row limit (the same happens with Schedulable).
I am now trying to solve this through Database.Batchable, but from what I understand of batch processing, it's designed to split a single query returning a large number of records into parts for processing, which is not what I need: I need to process many records from multiple objects for a specific user and get results.
Is there any approach you can recommend for further investigation to reach a solution? Thank you very much!!!

batchables have state (via implenents Database.Stateful) so you might be able to do your incremeental calcs in each batchable execute() and publish the PDF w CSV in the finish()

And queueables can be chained with state - requeuing with this keeps that state available for the next step in the sequence.

Yes, I have implemented logic to chain the jobs, and it works well. The problem is that it does not renew the limit package for each job; instead, it counts the total for all the jobs in the queue. This is why I easily exceed the limit of 50k queried records. Regarding batch processing, what I don't know how to do is the start, since I don't need records from a single object to process them, and that's where I have the problem: determining what the batch would be. Somehow, I should obtain all the records from multiple objects to process them.

The problem is that it does not renew the limit package for each job; instead, it counts the total for all the jobs in the queue - Please take a moment to read How to Ask and take the tour. Including a Minimal, Complete and Reproducible example would be helpful.

I was able to solve it! Basically, I created a batch class. In its start method, I placed the query for evaluated users, and when activating the job, the batch size is 1, so each batch belongs to a single user. This works; I really don't understand why it doesn't break the limits, but in all the tests I did, the metrics are correct, and it allows me to calculate reports for date ranges longer than a year.
